# Use getElementsByClassName for selecting 2 classes, with one being the variable of the function

Tags: javascript

In a Javascript function, I would like to select all elements that are class1 AND class2. But where "class1"=X and X is the variable of myfunction(X).

An example:

```js
function myfunction(X) {
 var list = document.getElementsByClassName(X, "class2");
 var listAll = document.getElementsByClassName("All");
 
     for(var t=0;t<listAll.length;t++)
    listAll[t].style.display="none";
    
     for(var y=0;y<list.length;y++)
    list[y].style.display="block";
 
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myfunction('class1')">Click to select only class1 X 2</button>
<button class="All class1">Class: 1</button>
<button class="All class1 class2">Class: 1 X 2</button>
<button class="All class2">Class: 2</button>
```

How can I change *var* list = document.getElementsByClassName(X, "class2") to only target element that are class 1 AND 2 ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) accepts a **single** argument, which is a space-delimited list of classes that each element in the result must have. So:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName(X + " class2");
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Live Example:

```js
function myfunction(X) {
 var list = document.getElementsByClassName(X + " class2");
 var listAll = document.getElementsByClassName("All");
 
     for(var t=0;t<listAll.length;t++)
    listAll[t].style.display="none";
    
     for(var y=0;y<list.length;y++)
    list[y].style.display="block";
 
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myfunction('class1')">Click to select only class1 X 2</button>
<button class="All class1">Class: 1</button>
<button class="All class1 class2">Class: 1 X 2</button>
<button class="All class2">Class: 2</button>
```

Alternatively, you can give any CSS selector (including a compound class selector) to [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get a snapshot `NodeList` instead of a live `HTMLCollection`.

Comment: That's a good one, thanks a lot !
If I understood well, the space is needed before class2 to match the listing style of the live HTML collection?
Anyway thanks that was a tricky detail

Comment: @Naga - It's just the way `getElementsByClassName` works, if you want to match on multiple classes, you list the classes with spaces in them: `.getElementsByClassName("class1 class2")`. Since `X` won't have a space, I included it in the string following it. (Spaces at the beginning or end of the string are ignored.)

Answer (score 1):

Just use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".class1.class2");
```

Also use eventListener and classList.toggle

```js
document.getElementById("sel").addEventListener("click",function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".All")].forEach(el => el.classList.toggle("hide",1));
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".class1.class2")].forEach(el => el.classList.toggle("hide",0));
})
```

```css
.hide { display: none }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="sel" >Click to select only class1 X 2</button>
<button type="button" class="All class1">Class: 1</button>
<button type="button" class="All class1 class2">Class: 1 X 2</button>
<button type="button" class="All class2">Class: 2</button>
```

If you want to pass in a class, try this:

```js
document.getElementById("sel").addEventListener("click",function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".All")].forEach(el => el.classList.toggle("hide",1));
  [...document.querySelectorAll(this.dataset.select+".class2")].forEach(el => el.classList.toggle("hide",0));
})
```

```css
.hide { display: none }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="sel" data-select=".class1">Click to select class1 plus class 2</button>
<button type="button" class="All class1">Class: 1</button>
<button type="button" class="All class1 class2">Class: 1 X 2</button>
<button type="button" class="All class2">Class: 2</button>
```

Comment: Thanks ! Though I need to use this X in my function(X) style for my project purpose.

Comment: The `X` is now a data attribute in the second example